# QPrinter, QPrintDialog giving errors not encountered in code examples

Tags: qt

In the imageviewer example, QPainter and QPrintDialog objects are defined and used as following:

```
#ifndef QT_NO_PRINTER
QPrinter printer;
#endif
```

and

```
QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);
```

A QPainter object is then initialized with QPrinter (printer).

When I tried to use the same code in my function, it looks like:

```
void imageviewer::print()
{
...
#ifdef QT_NO_PRINTER

QPrinter printer(this);             //ERROR 1
QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);//ERROR 2 and 3

if (dialog.exec())                  //ERROR 4
{
    //do the painting
}

#endif
}
```

The errors are:

```
1. variable 'QPrinter printer' has initializer but incomplete type
2. 'QPrintDialog' was not declared in this scope
3. Expected ';' before 'dialog'
4. 'dialog' was not declared in this scope
```

What I am not able to understand is why are these errors arising when I am using them in my code, but not in the example.

As a friend pointed out, I made sure that I used the right #include files and made sure that 'printer' and 'dialog' were not touched anywhere else in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `#ifdef QT_NO_PRINTER` in your code but the example uses `#ifndef QT_NO_PRINTER`

Pay attention to difference between **if not defined** and **if defined**

If your code compiles then it means that you have QT_NO_PRINTER in your project. Without a printer you can not print !

Comment: did it both ways i.e. with #ifdef and #ifndef.. in the latter case control does not enter the #if-else

Comment: QT_NO_PRINTER is a preprocessor directive. You need to remove it from your project. If your QT SDK has been compiled with printer support you should be fine. Otherwise you will get "unresolved external symbol for QPrinter" error. First remove this directive from your project if you want to print !

Answer (score 1):

```
QPrinter printer(this);
```

This is declaring a function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You need to write:

```
QPrinter printer = QPrinter(this);
```

or:

```
QPrinter printer((this));
```

Comment: Thank you @Alan Birtles for your answer. It has been more than four years since I asked this question and I am no longer working with Qt, or as a professional  programmer for that matter. But thank you for answering and reminding me of this.